# Solving an equation with 2 variables and 3 parameters

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find values of ${a,b,c}$ such that the equation has real solutions for $x , y ∈ [0, 1000]$.
I tried to implement:

```
   Reduce[(Abs[a - b]*x*y + Abs[a - c]*(1000*x - x^2 - x*y) 
+ Abs[b - c]*(1000*y - x*y - y^2))/(1000*(a*x + b*y + 1000*c - c*x - c*y)) == 0.4, {x, y}]
```

where $a,b,c>0$.

but it gives me no solutions.
Is there a way I can calculate that?

Comment: I would try FindMinimum of the function, which is more efficient than Solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContourPlot3D` allows you to see there are surfaces in parameter space where solutions exist. Unfortunately there isn't a 5D version, but you can keep varying the values of $a$ and $b$.

```
plot3d = ContourPlot3D[(f /. a -> 1 /. b -> 1) == 0, {c, 0, 1}, {x, 0,
    1000}, {y, 0, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"c", "x", "y"}]
```

[image]

Another option is to use `FindInstance`, which returns a single solution immediately, but doesn't seem to want to give me multiple solutions when I request them via the additional options

```
FindInstance[f == 0 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && 0 <= x <= 1000 && 
  0 <= y <= 1000, {a, b, c, x, y}]

(* {{a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 599/400599, x -> 0, y -> 1}} *)
```

`FindMinimum` is very good at finding a point though:

```
FindMinimum[{f^2, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, 0 <= x <= 1000,    0 <= y <= 1000}, {a, b, c, x, y}]
```

and if we repeated call this with different random initial conditions we can start to build up a 3D parameter plane:

```
tabb = Monitor[
   Table[FindMinimum[{f^2, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, 0 <= x <= 1000, 
        0 <= y <= 
         1000}, {{a, #1}, {b, #2}, {c, #3}, {x, #4}, {y, #5}}, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 10] &@(Sequence @@ 
       RandomReal[{0, 1000}, 5]), {i, 1000}], i];
pts= {a, b, c, x, y} /. Pick[tabb[[All, 2]], Thread[tabb[[All, 1]] < 10^-10]]
```

This looks somewhat random, but there is some clear structure:

```
ListPlot[pts[[All, {1, 3}]], AxesLabel -> {"a", "c"}]
```

[image]

Limiting the range of the `RandomReal` or fixing $x$ and $y$ may well help.

Answer (score 4):

A good strategy is to use `SolveAlways[eqns,vars]` that gives values of parameters that make the equations `eqns` valid for all values of the variables `vars`.

In particular, by defining:

```
f = (Abs[a - b] x y + Abs[a - c] (1000 x - x^2 - x y) + Abs[b - c]
    (1000 y - x y - y^2))/(1000 (a x + b y + 1000 c - c x - c y)) - 2/5;
```

writing:

```
SolveAlways[f == 0, {x, y}]
```

we get:

> {{a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0}}

while writing:

```
SolveAlways[f == 0, x]
```

we get:

> {{a -> 0, c -> 0, y -> 0}, 
>     {a -> 0, c -> 0, y -> 600}, 
>     {a -> 0, c -> 0, y -> 1400}, 
>     {a -> c, b -> 0, y -> -400}, 
>     {a -> c, b -> 0, y -> 400}, 
>     {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, y -> 100 (5 - Sqrt[41])}, 
>     {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, y -> 100 (5 + Sqrt[41])}, 
>     {a -> c, b -> c/6, y -> 600}, {a -> c, b -> (9 c)/14, y -> 1400}, 
>     {a -> c, b -> (14 c)/9, y -> -400}, 
>     {a -> c, b -> 6 c, y -> 400}, {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0}, 
>     {a -> c, b -> (c (400000 - 1400 y + y^2))/((-1400 + y) y)}, 
>     {a -> c, b -> (c (-400000 - 600 y + y^2))/((-600 + y) y)}}

and similarly, writing:

```
SolveAlways[f == 0, y]
```

we get:

> {{a -> 0, b -> c, x -> -400}, 
>      {a -> 0, b -> c, x -> 400}, 
>      {b -> 0, c -> 0, x -> 0}, 
>      {b -> 0, c -> 0, x -> 600}, 
>      {b -> 0, c -> 0, x -> 1400}, 
>      {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, x -> 100 (5 - Sqrt[41])}, 
>      {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, x -> 100 (5 + Sqrt[41])}, 
>      {a -> c/6, b -> c, x -> 600}, 
>      {a -> (9 c)/14, b -> c, x -> 1400}, 
>      {a -> (14 c)/9, b -> c, x -> -400}, 
>      {a -> 6 c, b -> c, x -> 400}, 
>      {a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0}, 
>      {a -> (c (400000 - 1400 x + x^2))/((-1400 + x) x), b -> c}, 
>      {a -> (c (-400000 - 600 x + x^2))/((-600 + x) x), b -> c}}

All that remains is to select the solutions of interest.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's super helpful!!